# Is it possible to Re-Sync the testcases in ALM which are in approved status?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I have some test cases which are approved status in ALM, I want to re-sync these test cases using PAF. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Manually we have to change the status from approved to "**To be updated**" in ALM and make sure your alm_test_id is same , and follow the steps to sync.
Sync/Upload the test case to ALM using the eclipse configuration “ALM Sync”

```
createTestCase [flow_id] [flow_xml_path]
```